# How to inject a react app based chrome extension inside a webpage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm developing a react app based chrome extension which uses Google's material design and has a couple of pages with navigation.

I want to inject the extension inside the browser tab when the extension is launched from the browser address toolbar. I've seen multiple extensions do so by injecting a div(inside the body of webpage) containing an iframe with src equal to the extension's pop-up HTML page.

I execute the following function when the extension is launched. Which basically injects the extension into the target webpage body but it appears multiple times inside the target web page.

```
function main() {
 
 const extensionOrigin = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id;

 if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
 
 // Fetch the local React index.html page
 
 fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html") /*, options */)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((html) => {

 const styleStashHTML = html.replace(
          /\/static\//g,
 `${extensionOrigin}/static/`
        );

 const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

 $(styleStashHTML).appendTo(body);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
 console.warn(error);
      });
  }
}
```

[See Image of Incorrect Injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhG5L.jpg)

Any help or guidance would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use devtools to debug your code: it runs twice for some reason. You can set a breakpoint inside main() and reload the page to see when this function is called.

Comment: It may happen if you have `all_frames` true in manifest.json which makes the content script run in all iframes.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes it was true and setting it to false did solve the issue. Thank you so much!